# When display data from table in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC on view model nothing display although table have multiple rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC app. I have a table `cinimas` with 5 rows.

My issue I can't display these 5 rows in my custom view model.

I try but no rows are displayed.

What I tried:

**Step 1**: model creation

```
public class Cinema : IEntityBase
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cinema Logo")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cinema logo is required")]
        public string Logo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cinema Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cinema name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 2**: create custom model view that will display data as view models from table:

```
public class CinimaViewModels
{
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 3**: create service interface `ICinemasService` with definition for data display:

```
public interface ICinemasService:IEntityBaseRepository<Cinema>
{
    IQueryable<CinimaViewModels>GetAllCinimas();
}
```

**Step 4**: implement that interface in `CinemasService` class

```
public class CinemasService:EntityBaseRepository<Cinema>, ICinemasService
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public CinemasService(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public  IQueryable<CinimaViewModels> GetAllCinimas()
    {
        var cinmas = new Cinema();
         
        var response = new List<CinimaViewModels>
            {
                new CinimaViewModels 
                    {
                        Description = cinmas.Description,
                        Logo = cinmas.Logo,
                        Name = cinmas.Name
                    }
            };

        return response.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

In step 4, no are rows returned although table does have 5 rows.

So how to solve this issue?

I need to return data on custom view model `CinimaViewModels` as `IQueryable` but nothing is displayed.

How to solve this issue?

**Update**: I checked this to return data from model it return 5 rows as below:

```
var cinmas2 = _context.Cinemas.ToList();
```

but from view model on step 4 as above nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the data in database,you should read from dbcontext,instead of create a new instance;

in your GetAllCinimas method,you could try as below:

```
public IQueryable<CinimaViewModel> GetAllCinimas()
        {
            var response = _context.Cinema.Select(x => new CinimaViewModel() { Logo = x.Logo, Name = x.Name });


            return response;


        }
```

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/data-transformations-with-linq) related with Data Transformations with LINQ

If you have further issue, please show more details

Comment: are there are another way without using LINQ

Comment: if there are another way without using linq please give me if please

Comment: If you want to try with Basic SQL queries, you could check this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#basic-sql-queries